# BadImageFormatException when deploying on Hololens

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, badimageformatexception

I'm currently part of a small team working on a project for HoloLens.
We're facing a problem when deploying on an unit: My team-mate can deploy from his computer and run the program, but when I do it from mine, on the same unit, it refuses to launch and throws a BadImageFormatException.

If I deploy the same program, from my computer, but on another HoloLens it works flawlessly.

The emulator works too, but there are too many limitations for what we intend to do.

Has any other team encountered the same problem when deploying the same program from two different computers to a single HoloLens ?

**edit**
Sorry I wasn't specific enough: The program is built with Unity, then deployed through Visual Studio.
The message sent with the exception is about the application not being a valid x86 app. (I'll copy-paste the exception tomorrow)
Of course the application is valid, as I said before: I can deploy it without any problem on another device.
The exception is thrown from the constructor of the **App** class, before the application starts properly (the "Made with Unity" splashscreen doesn't show up):

```
public App()
{
    SetupOrientation();
    m_AppCallbacks = new AppCallbacks(); // <-- Exception is thrown from this point.

    // Allow clients of this class to append their own callbacks.
    AddAppCallbacks(m_AppCallbacks);
}
```

Comment: You should paste the used code for the loading of the image. Also, where is the image from? Server? Resources? Editor connection?

Comment: I added more information about the context. Unity generates the code that will be built and deployed through Visual Studio. I'm guessing the source of the problem is the origin of the code deployed. As the device already contains a version of the program, if we try to deploy another version from another computer, Visual Studio only tries to update the package instead of re-installing it from scratch. As the package comes from another computer (and has another signature ?), incompatibility ensues...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by checking the "uninstall and then reinstall my package" in the project properties in Visual Studio.
Now Visual studio redeploys the whole package every time, but there are no longer any conflicts.